# How to get plain text messages validating with QXmlSchema?

Tags: xml, qt, xsd, xsd-validation

I am validating XML source files with a custom XSD schema file. The process is running on Qt, using `QXmlSchema`class the usual way.

```
/**
 * Validate the OFXML document against the OFXML schema.
 */
bool OfmlValidator::validateXMLSyntax() {
  static const QString engine = "XML Validator";
  static const QString filePath = "/Users/james/temp/myxml.xsd";

  // Check that the .xsd file exists
  QFile file(filePath);
  if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
    issues->append(Issue::getErrorInstance(engine, "Unexpected: Could not find XSD schema file at '" + filePath + "'."));
    return false;
  }
  const QByteArray schemaData = file.readAll();

  // Create a schema object and assign a message handler
  MyXmlParserHandler *handler = new MyXmlParserHandler();
  QXmlSchema schema;
  schema.setMessageHandler(handler);

  // Load the schema
  schema.load(schemaData);
  if (!schema.isValid()) {
    issues->append(Issue::getErrorInstance(engine, "Unexpected: The XSD file is not a valid XML Schema file."));
    return false;
  } else {
    // Validate the source against the schema
    const QByteArray sourceData = source.toUtf8();
    QXmlSchemaValidator validator(schema);
    if (validator.validate(sourceData)) {
      issues->append(Issue::getSuccessInstance(engine, "Valid XML source."));
      return true;
    } else {
      issues->append(Issue::getErrorInstance(engine, handler->statusMessage(), QString::number(handler->line())));
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Though it may not be relevant, here is the `MyXmlParserHandler.h` declaration

```
#ifndef MYXML_PARSER_HANDLER_H
#define MYXML_PARSER_HANDLER_H
#include "issue.h"

#include <QAbstractMessageHandler>

class MyXmlParserHandler : public QAbstractMessageHandler {

public:
  MyXmlParserHandler();
  QString statusMessage() const;
  int line() const;
  int column() const;
  QString messageType() const;

protected:
  virtual void handleMessage(QtMsgType type, const QString &message, const QUrl &identifier, const QSourceLocation &location);

private:
  QtMsgType type;
  QString message;
  QSourceLocation location;
};

#endif // MYXML_PARSER_HANDLER_H
```

and the `MyXmlParserHandler.cpp` code

```
#include "ofxml-parser-handler.h"

MyXmlParserHandler::MyXmlParserHandler() : QAbstractMessageHandler (nullptr) {
  type = QtDebugMsg;
  message = "";
  location = QSourceLocation();
}

QString MyXmlParserHandler::statusMessage() const {
  return message;
}

int MyXmlParserHandler::line() const {
  return location.line();
}

int MyXmlParserHandler::column() const {
  return location.column();
}

QString MyXmlParserHandler::messageType() const {
  switch (type) {
    case QtDebugMsg: return "Debug";
    case QtWarningMsg: return "Warning";
    case QtCriticalMsg: return "Error";
    case QtFatalMsg: return "Error";
    default: return "Unknown";
  }
}

void MyXmlParserHandler::handleMessage(QtMsgType type, const QString &message, const QUrl &identifier, const QSourceLocation &location) {
  Q_UNUSED(type);
  Q_UNUSED(identifier);

  this->type = type;
  this->message = message;
  this->location = location;
}
```

The code is validating according to my expectations but **the error messages issued by QXmlSchema are XHTML encoded** (?).

For example, if the standard root element should be `<document>` (as described in the XSD file) and `<doc>` is used instead, the following error is returned.

```
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/'><body><p>No definition for element <span class='XQuery-keyword'>doc</span> available.</p></body></html> at 2
```

My problem is that **I did not expected to handle XHTML at this point**, but simple plain text errors. This code is part of a larger application that handles many other situations where errors can happen and they always are reported in a plain text fashion.

So I came here to ask a question to grow my knowledge:

**Why the errors are presented in XHTML syntax?**

and get some help:

Is it possible to **change the default QXmlSchema behavior** to make it issuing plain text errors?

Is there an **easy and simple way of transforming XHTML into plain text?**